# ASP.NET cosmosDB, Ignore extra elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

Just curious, I came from a *Mongodb* background but I'm making the switch to *CosmosDBs* core SQL database. I cant seem to find an ignore extra elements attributes(mongo has `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]`. My cursory google searches have also not turned up much.

Anyone have any idea on this one?

**Clarification**

Basically *CosmosDB* doesn't have predefined classes setup(it basically stores raw *json*). Therefore, in the future should we add more elements to a database context class, we don't want our server to blow up. This is established in normal SQL with a bool you pass to the EF Core client, and on mongo with the mentioned attribute.

Additionally, I have looked at `JsonIgnore`. However, it would mean I would have to know ahead of time what element I wish to ignore.

I'm looking for something which will ignore all unknown elements. This will allow for flexibility to add elements to a context connected to the same database without compromising the operation of previous versions(Or without having to go back and edit old versions with `JsonIgnore` which can become quite the burden)

Comment: Define extra elements? what is is you are trying to do or want to do. This will make it easier for non mongo DB programmers to help you

Comment: Basically CosmosDB doesnt have predefined classes setup(it basically stores raw json). Therefore, in the future should we add more elements to a database context class, we don't want our server to blow up. This is established in normal SQL with a bool you pass to the EF Core client, and on mongo with the mentioned attribute.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output please?

Comment: So, Lets say you have a json string that your asp server receives from the document database. It will then attempt to parse the json into a class that you set beforehand. The issue would arise when you must maintain previous versions of your classes (for compatibility with older versions of your frontend) This sets a restriction that we cannot change or remove already established elements without releasing a hotfix for the earlier versions. However, historically we have been able to add elements to the given class because previous versions of our app were set to ignore extra elements.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting everyones time on this one. I decided to do a check myself and it appears that cosmos core defaults to ignoring extra elements, Which can be good or bad depending on how you look at it. Its important to note that it will throw exceptions if you switch it over to the mongo wrapper instead of core though.